# Upload single file in UpdatePanel without FullPostBack

Tags: c#, updatepanel, dotnetnuke, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i know there is a lot of posts about this, but i cant find any working solution. I need upload one single file in updatepanel without fullpostback. Is it possible without flash ? I was trying to implement AjaxControlToolKit (AjaxFileUpload) but its not working. In new version i have black button. In older i see it like here:
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

but on upload, its going to page_load and then i get this error:
ajaxfileupload Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON

Im working on DotNetNuke 7

pls help :D im frustrated :D